# Can I find eigenvalues for $A$ if I know the eigenvalues from $AA^T$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, generalized-eigenvector

Let's say we have a real matrix $A$ and I find the eigenvalues for $\sqrt{AA^T}$. Is it possible for me then to find the eigenvalues for $A$ without using

$$det(A-\lambda I)=0$$

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, take 
$$ A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&-1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
The eigenvalues of $A^TA$ are $1$ with geometric multiplicity two. If we knew that $A$ were positive (i.e. self-adjoint  and having only positive eigenvalues), then taking square roots *would* recover the eigenvalues. Basically, the issue here is the sign.

Comment: More generally, any orthogonal matrix will be indistinguishable!

Comment: So is there any way to compute the eigenvalues without the generalized method?

Comment: There is a way in theory: consult Lax's Linear Algebra book for a variational characterization of eigenvalues as solutions to min/max problems. It involves something called the "Rayleigh Quotient."

Comment: like this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient_iteration

Comment: More along these lines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient.

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis Isn't there any more practical method to find the eigenvalues of a matrix A?

Comment: The best way I know is the $\det(A-\lambda I)$ method. There are some good numerical methods for approximate solutions I'm sure, but I don't know much about them.